# Ruby cannot copy files from a remote share

Tags: ruby

When trying to copy files from a remote Windows share to a local folder I'm getting a `Permission denied` error.

```
remote_path = '\\\\reomte_machine\remote_folder'
destination = 'local_folder'
FileUtils.cp(remote_path, destination)
```

I have access to the remote folder and I'm allowed to copy files manually. Is something wrong with the way I'm trying to copy the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [cp_r](http://apidock.com/ruby/FileUtils/cp_r) instead of [cp](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/FileUtils/cp/class):

```
FileUtils.cp_r(remote_path, destination)
```